# How can I convert from a Netpbm image to a Gtk pixbuf (in Haskell)?

Tags: haskell, image-processing, gtk

I'm working on an application in which the best way I have (so far) found to manipulate images is with the Graphics.Netpbm library.  I'll be delegating many operations, such as raw file development, to an external application, and I just wanted a very clean well-supported format.

I actually got it working.  I can tell ufraw-batch to "develop" a raw file and output the result in pnm format to stdout.  Graphics.Netpbm.parsePPM parses the image just fine.  Then I need to convert it into a pixbuf to display in a GtkImage widget, and while I have a solution, I think it is pretty gross.  I would love a better way to do it.

When reading this wall of code, you can skip the entire `let` declaration and understand that `img_list :: Netpbm.PPM -> [CUChar]`.

```
display_image :: Graphics.UI.Gtk.Image -> Netpbm.PPM -> IO ()
display_image canvas image_bitmap =
    let get_rgb_vector = Netpbm.pixelVectorToList . (\(Netpbm.PpmPixelDataRGB8 v) -> v) . Netpbm.ppmData
        vector_to_cuchar_list = map CUChar . concat . map (\(Netpbm.PpmPixelRGB8 r g b) -> r:g:b:[])
        img_list = vector_to_cuchar_list . get_rgb_vector
        len = length . img_list
        width = Netpbm.ppmWidth . Netpbm.ppmHeader
        height = Netpbm.ppmHeight . Netpbm.ppmHeader
    in do
    img_ptr <- mallocBytes (len image_bitmap)
    mapM_ (\(b, off) -> pokeByteOff img_ptr off (b :: CUChar)) (zip (img_list image_bitmap) [0,1..])
    pb <- pixbufNewFromData img_ptr ColorspaceRgb False 8 (width image_bitmap) (height image_bitmap) ((width image_bitmap) * 3)
    imageSetFromPixbuf canvas pb
```

The function at the top starts with a lot of utilities to actually get to the raw pixel data.  They're pretty messy, too, and I don't really know a better way to organize them yet.  But the gross part is in the do block.  I allocate a C array of bytes to store all the data.  Then I iterate over the [CUChar] that represents the image, poking each individual byte into the correct location in the C array.  And then I create a GtkPixbuf from that data.

Ug.  What is a faster, cleaner, *safer* way to do this?

pixbufNewFromData accepts a `Ptr CUChar` as the first parameter, where Netpbm with all the unwrapping ultimately can provide me with a `[Word8]`.  So in my view, I need a clean function that does `[Word8] -> Ptr CUChar`.  It need not be pure.

I also don't mind doing a major change, but my data flow overall is

```
operation that generates a ByteString of pnm data ---> GtkImage
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me start with syntax-rewriting your code equivalently:

```
{-# LANGUAGE NamedFieldPuns #-}

display_image :: Graphics.UI.Gtk.Image -> Netpbm.PPM -> IO ()
display_image canvas PPM{ ppmData 
                        , ppmHeader = PPMHeader{ ppmWidth  = width
                                               , ppmHeight = height } } = do

    let word8s :: [Word8]
        word8s = case ppmData of

            PpmPixelDataRGB8 vec -> concat [ [r,g,b] | PpmPixelRGB8 r g b <- Netpbm.pixelVectorToList vec ]
            _ -> error "expected RGB8 data"

    img_ptr <- mallocBytes (length word8s)

    forM_ (zip word8s [0..]) $ \(word8, off) ->
        pokeByteOff img_ptr off (CUChar word8)

    pb <- pixbufNewFromData img_ptr ColorspaceRgb False 8 width height (width * 3)
    imageSetFromPixbuf canvas pb
```

Now the safer way, simply using `newArray` to convert the list to a Ptr:

```
import Foreign.Marshal.Array (newArray)

    img_ptr <- newArray (map CUChar word8s)
    pb <- pixbufNewFromData img_ptr ColorspaceRgb False 8 width height (width * 3)
    imageSetFromPixbuf canvas pb
```

This is quite short and easy to read.

- Note that if `pixbufNewFromData` makes its own copy of the data, use `allocaBytes` instead of `mallocBytes`, and `withArray` instead of `newArray`. Otherwise, you will memory leak the `malloc`.

---

If instead of a safe way you want a faster way, do not convert to lists and operate straight via the unboxed `U.Vector`:

```
import qualified Data.Vector.Unboxed as U

    case ppmData of

        PpmPixelDataRGB8 vec -> do

            let len = U.length vec

            img_ptr <- mallocBytes len

            forM_ [0..len-1] $ \i -> do
                let PpmPixelRGB8 r g b = vec U.! i
                pokeByteOff img_ptr (3 * off    ) r
                pokeByteOff img_ptr (3 * off + 1) g
                pokeByteOff img_ptr (3 * off + 2) b

            pb <- pixbufNewFromData img_ptr ColorspaceRgb False 8 width height (width * 3)
            imageSetFromPixbuf canvas pb

        _ -> error "expected RGB8 data"
```

- An even faster way would be to change [netpbm](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/netpbm) (I wrote it, contributions welcome) and make it use `Vector.Storable` instead of `Vector.Unboxed` - then you could directly obtain a `Ptr` to the data without doing anything.
- You probably don't need this faster version since most probably parsing the text-based PPM files will be the bottleneck, not accessing the parsed data.

---

**Update:** I have just released [netpbm-1.0.0](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/netpbm-1.0.0) which features `Storable` instead of `Unboxed` vectors inside.

You can thus use

```
S.unsafeWith vec $ \ppmPixelRgb8Ptr -> do
    let word8Ptr = castPtr (ppmPixelRgb8Ptr :: Ptr PpmPixelDataRGB8)
    -- do something with the Ptr
```

Comment: I'm not ignoring this, but I actually broke my computer about the time you posted. I've been waiting for repairs ever since, and I will try all of this out when the system comes back to me.